# Accessing local server with iOS 9.2 and Xcode 7.2 using localhost

Tags: ios, localhost

I just upgrade to iOS 9.2 and Xcode 7.2 and now my app can't access the local API server debugging in the device using *http://localhost* (on simulator it works like a charm). I changed the address to my local network IP (*192.168.0.3*) and it worked but I'd like to know if there is some setting or something like that to work with *localhost* again.

Answer (score 3):

And this should not work, `localhost` is the device it self not your  machine which is running you API server.

It work on the simulator because it is running on the machine, so `localhost` will resolve to the same machine.

You should use either your public IP or host name from your device.

Comment: For sure @rckoenes. It makes sense but it's strange it was working on Xcode 7.1. Thanks!

Comment: I see no reason why it should have work with xcode 7.1 Since you iPhone is not running the server I could not have connected to `localhost`.

Answer (score -1):

This could be a network issue, suppose, if your device and your mac (xcode running) is not in the same wireless network, I had the same problem, my device was not connecting on my 4G network, whereas my computer was on my wireless network.